# Optimizing millions of points render using python

Tags: python, optimization, opengl, pygame, 2d

I am trying to display a million points in 2D using pygame and (maybe) openGL.

The problem is, my code isn't optimized yet to make it run at a high frame rate, even though I have a really good GPU.

Here is the first method i used, it is running at around 2 FPS for 1 million points, which isn't so bad but I want it to be at least 60 FPS :

```
for i in range(len(positions)): 
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, positions[i], circle_radius)
```

And here is the second method, which is even worse (1 FPS), using OpenGL :

```
for i in range(len(positions)): 
        glVertex2f(positions[i][0], positions[i][1])
```

I thought OpenGL would be more optimized than pygame but it seems not.

What would be a better way to display these points? Is it a library problem or can I do it a much better way using OpenGL?

Comment: You are using the OpenGL fixed function pipeline (`glVertex2f`). These OpenGL methods are pretty outdated since a decade. Please look into modern OpenGL (> OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile) with Vertex Buffer Objects.

Comment: Something to note about using Pygame: Pygame does not use your GPU for rendering normally so this is the reason why the first variant is not accelerated by your GPU. Maybe you do not even need to redraw the points every frame (i.e. draw the points on a surface and then blit this surface to the screen and change that surface only once there is a change to the points), maybe this works for your project.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really an expert with OpenGL so this code should be used with care.
This code might not be appropriate when changing of points is required frequently.

On my machine it already runs with about 120FPS using the iGPU.

```py
import pygame
from OpenGL.GL import *
import random

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Initialize the pygame screen
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

# setup extra stuff
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# setup open gl
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)  # clear with black
glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()


def draw_text(x_pos, y_pos, text):
    # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/67639147/7380827
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, (255, 255, 66, 255), (0, 66, 0, 255))
    text_data = pygame.image.tostring(text_surface, "RGBA", True)
    glWindowPos2d(x_pos, y_pos)
    glDrawPixels(text_surface.get_width(), text_surface.get_height(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text_data)


def main():
    # Generate random points
    num_points = 1_000_000
    points = [(random.randint(0, WIDTH), random.randint(0, HEIGHT)) for _ in range(num_points)]

    # Flatten the point data
    flattened_points = [p for point in points for p in point]

    # Create a VBO
    vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)  # bind
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(flattened_points) * 4,
                 (ctypes.c_float * len(flattened_points))(*flattened_points), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)  # unbind

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        # Bind the VBO and draw points using OpenGL
        glPointSize(2)  # set the size of the points here
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)  # bind
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)  # point color
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, len(points))
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)  # unbind

        draw_text(0, 0, 'FPS: {}'.format(int(clock.get_fps())))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick()

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The size of the points can be changed using `glPointSize(size)`. I used 2 as an example (if a bigger size is used the outcome will be solid red because of the large amount of points).

Comment: I'd recommend using custom shaders and VAOs for full compatibility with Core profile, but the code looks good. The only thing you might want to explain is why you picked a point size of 1.1

Comment: @BDL I changed the value to 2.